# Can I use my TWIC card as my photo ID to fly from Philadelphia to Las Vegas?

Tags: air-travel, usa, identity-cards

I live in the United States and I'm traveling from Philadelphia International Airport to McCarran Airport in Las Vegas. My passport has expired and I have misplaced my driver's license. I am trying to save money and time by using my Transportation Worker Identification Credentials (TWIC Card) as my photo ID to board the plane.

It was issued to work at the power plant, which is located in the port. Anybody working at any port in the US needs this card to be able to enter it. Applying for it is similar to applying for a passport. So it is not an easy credential to obtain. There is a little chip in it that is like a SIM card and has everything the government would want to know about me on it. It is a federally-issued card and has my photo on it.

Will I be able to use this to board the plane, or will I have to deal with the long lines at the DMV and get a new license made?

Comment: Note that driving without a license will get you a ticket one day (and a lot of trouble in an accident), so not renewing it should only be a temporary solution.

Comment: @Aganju some US states only require drivers to be licensed, not to carry the license with them when driving.  I don't know whether this is the case in Nevada, but if the OP lives in New Hampshire, it may not be a very high priority to find the license (which is "misplaced," not expired).

Comment: [As of 2020, a TWIC also gets you PreCheck.](https://www.tsa.gov/news/press/releases/2020/07/08/active-twicr-and-hme-holders-can-use-their-credentials-obtain-tsa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**YES.**

The TWIC is specifically listed as a valid credential on TSA's website.  [Identification](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification)

However, the screener might not recognize it immediately.  I have witnessed instances where less common identification was incorrectly questioned.

Comment: Interesting. What less common identification have you seen questioned?

Answer (score 9):

I have used a TWIC card as travel ID within the US for over a year.  I never show my driver's license and I do not have a passport.  I have found that every TSA agent recognizes the TWIC card because they themselves are required to have one in order to work at the airport.

Not only that, but because I wear my TWIC card on a lanyard around my neck, I often get the 10% airport employee discount at the airport lobby stores and food places because they think I work at the airport.  So, yes, the TWIC card is a valid ID for domestic air travel.

Comment: Now I'm going to have to try that TWIC on the lanyard trick!

Answer (score 0):

Not true! Traveling home from the New Orleans Airport through TSA Security and attempted to use my TWIC for my ID. The TSA agent refused and demanded a DL or Passport as identification. I asked why, when the TWIC is issued by the TSA and it was a "card reader" issue. Their equipment doesn't "read" their TSA-issued identification. (smh!)

Comment: Given this occurrence, travelers using a TWIC for identification should also carry a printout or reference to TSA's [Identification page](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), which shows a TWIC as acceptable ID.